# How does a Java ResultSet object react when next() is called, if the SQL server execution plan is streaming data?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, inputstream, resultset

I have a scenario which I can't find a clear answer to on the SQL server jdbc documentation.

I know from the execution plan for my SQL query that it will begin to steam data back as soon as it's found the first result, but that the results will be found sporadically in my very large data set.

When I call next() on my ResultSet initially there will only be N number of rows out of the eventual total. In this assumption I assume the fetch size is higher than the number of rows ready to be passed onto my java code from the SQL server. After I have processed these I would call next() again to get the next batch of results, but if SQL server is still executing the query, but not found any rows to return yet, what will the ResultSet do?

I tried setting up a test, but I couldn't  get any conclusive results. Does anyone know any documentation surrounding how this works? If the java JDBC doesn't specify how it should work then I specifically care about the latest SQL server 2017 drivers.

Comment: You should have a look at the official documentation for more deeper understanding. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()

Comment: Can you share your code and your efforts, will be more clear to help further.

Comment: I've already read that documentation, it doesn't cover how the ResultSet will behave in this specific scenario. The example code is literally just me calling next() on a ResultSet for a streaming SQL server query.